# In Django, how can I use project wide static files?

Tags: django

At the moment I have

```
myproject/app1
```

And I am adding a second app in and I wish to share some common JS and CSS

I have moved my static files from

```
myproject/app1/static
```

to

```
myproject/static
```

What configuration changes do I have to make for the applications to recognize the new location?  I don't remember ever setting the directory initially I think it just worked out of the box

Comment: you have to update your media settings and you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py`, declare the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Also, add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` if it isn't already.

Comment: @Melvyn I'm not sure why you think this isn't the fix, as the **OP has marked this answer as correct**. Care to explain/provide an alternative solution?

Comment: See @dm295's answer. The issue is that static files aren't picked up that aren't part of an app. The answer below explains it in detail. In fact, these are defaults already in the settings file, so nothing changed.

Answer (score 6):

From [Django [1.11] Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/):

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your
>   apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your
>   settings file where Django will also look for static files.

Add to `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Assuming you are using `django.contrib.staticfiles` app.

Comment: That's the right answer. Shame it's been trimmed from the boilerplate settings, as it used to be in there.